# Adding XMP licencing information in PDFs in a standard compliant way (with exiftool?)

Tags: pdf, exiftool

(This is ultimately a question about the PDF standard, with the problem of embedding XMP licencing information and the behavior of `exiftool` in doing this being the reason for me asking it.)

I have just tried to embed licencing information into a(n uncompressed) PDF with `exiftool` by issuing the command

```
exiftool -XMP-dc:Rights="CC BY 4.0" my.pdf
```

I am looking for a stable and reliably way (that also works with compressed PDFs) of doing this and was hoping that a standard tool like `exiftool` would be the way to go.

The resulting PDF can still be opened fine, but looking into its content made me wonder whether the modifications `exiftool` performs actually conform with the PDF standard.

The original file ended with

```
[...]
1017 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Names 1016 0 R /OpenAction 105 0 R
/Outlines 973 0 R /PageMode /UseOutlines /Pages 972 0 R >>
endobj
[...]
trailer
<< /ID [ <9fe842ddcb590d8769ad14dc73cb68c4>
<a8e74b152bcd65822c59e4fc7a2e5103> ]
/Info 1018 0 R /Root 1017 0 R /Size 1022 >>
startxref
4377062
%%EOF
```

Note in particular that it contains an indirect object with `object number` 1017.

`exiftool` simply appends some stuff to the file after the `%%EOF` comment and leaves the rest of the file completely untouched, so that the result looks like this:

```
[...]
1017 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Names 1016 0 R /OpenAction 105 0 R
/Outlines 973 0 R /PageMode /UseOutlines /Pages 972 0 R >>
endobj
[...]
trailer
<< /ID [ <9fe842ddcb590d8769ad14dc73cb68c4>
<a8e74b152bcd65822c59e4fc7a2e5103> ]
/Info 1018 0 R /Root 1017 0 R /Size 1022 >>
startxref
4377062
%%EOF
%BeginExifToolUpdate      <------- Here exiftool starts appending
1017 0 obj                <------- This number was used before!
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Names 1016 0 R
/OpenAction 105 0 R
/Outlines 973 0 R
/PageMode /UseOutlines
/Pages 972 0 R
/Metadata 1022 0 R
>>
endobj
1022 0 obj
<<
/Type /Metadata
/Subtype /XML
/Length 2863
>>
stream
<?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
    [Supposedly correct XMP representation of the licence information]                                                                                                    
<?xpacket end='w'?>
endstream
endobj
xref
0 1
0000000000 65535 f 
1017 1
0004397692 00000 n 
1022 1
0004397842 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/ID [ <9fe842ddcb590d8769ad14dc73cb68c4> <a9e74b152bcd65822c59e4fc7a2e5103> ]
/Info 1018 0 R
/Root 1017 0 R
/Size 1023
/Prev 4377062
>>
%EndExifToolUpdate 4397671
startxref
4400791
%%EOF
```

The resulting file hence has TWO `trailer`s, contains the `%EOF` comment twice, and even contains now TWO objects with `object number` 1017.

I do know [a thing](https://amccormack.net/2012-01-22-anatomy-of-a-pdf-document.html) or [two](https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0005.html) about the PDF file specification and have the impression that this violates the PDF standard, but at the same time it seems unlikely that a standard program `exiftool` would make such obvious miskates? Hopefully someone with deeper knowledge of the PDF standard and/or `exiftool` can comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out (which I didn't know) that PDF allows mutiple `trailer`s and the overwriting of objects. This is nicely explained [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/11/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-multiple-trailers-on-a-pdf-file/), for example.